# Ошибка 405 Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

Ничего не знаю о Django, буквально неделю изучаю. При очередном запуске начало выдавать ошибку 405. Кода очень много кидать, поэтому если не трудно, скажите пожалуйста какие могут быть причины этой ошибки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка 405 Django может исходить из любого количества проблем, но обычно это заканчивается тем, что либо вы используете неправильный URL-адрес, либо используете неправильный метод запроса. Иногда и то, и другое!

Answer (score 0):

если у вашего представления определен только метод GET, то попытка отправить запрос с методом POST выдаст 405 Method Not Allowed

Как например у этой View

```
class MyView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return None
```